# android studio, hide package name in project explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

It just happened right after upgrading to v2.2, where androids studio is showing the full package name of the project for each package I create!

[image: here is how it looks]

Anyone has any idea how to hide the full package name and just showing the package name the I am creating?

Comment: There should be a gear icon above that... some thing about "flatten packages"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you have the `Flatten Packages` option active. To return to the default behavior you must turn this option off by going to your Project view at the left side (usually) and then on the click `Show Option Menu` Icon (a little cog on the top of this sidebar)

Image guide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoxfP.jpg

**EDIT: Sorry it seems I cannot yet post a comment to a reply ?**

There is currently a bug issued here about the same problem fairly recent

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222914

They suggest that the bug has to do with enabling `dataBindings` in your project and they already looking for a fix to this as we speak.

On the other hand if you do not have `dataBindings` enabled please try the following: Close AStudio, remove the .idea folder from your project, and then import your project again.

Comment: That is correct, I am actually using dataBindings! thx anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i was wandering what went wrong suddenly, very strange

Comment: Nice is answer,,,,, perfect.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been Fixed in Android Studio V2.2.1.